# Laravel 5: Trouble with putting correct data on screen after combining tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

As of right now, I'm working on a Laravel-5 project and I would like to build some sort of activity log. I do have a query that combines multiple tables and gives me the data I need, but as soon as I try to put the data on screen, things go wrong.

This is the query I am using right now in me ProfileController:

```
$activity = DB::select("SELECT user_id, created_at, source, project_id
    FROM (
        SELECT id as project_id, user_id, created_at, 'project' as source FROM projects
        UNION ALL SELECT project_id, user_id, created_at, 'comment' as source FROM comments
        UNION ALL SELECT project_id, user_id, created_at, 'favorite' as source FROM favorites
        UNION ALL SELECT project_id, user_id, created_at, 'like' as source FROM likes
    ) as a
    WHERE user_id = $id
    ORDER BY created_at DESC");
```

This is what the code in my profile.blade.php looks like:

```
<ul class="list-group">
@foreach($activity as $act)
    @if($act->source == 'project')
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ $act->user_id }} added a new project: {{ $act->project_id }}</li>
    @elseif($act->source == 'like')
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ $act->user_id }} likes {{ $act->project_id }}!</li>
    @elseif($act->source == 'comment')
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ $act->user_id }} commented on {{ $act->project_id }}</li>
    @elseif($act->source == 'favorite')
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ $act->user_id }} has {{ $act->project_id }} to his favourites!</li>
    @endif
@endforeach
</ul>
```

And this is what my models look like:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [

        'title',
        'description',
        'user_id',
        'snapshot',
        'views'
    ];

    public function creator() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function tags() {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag');
    }
}
```

---

```
class Likes extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'project_id'
    ];

    public function like() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function project() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Project', 'project_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'project_id',
        'comment'
    ];

    public function poster() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function project() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Project', 'project_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

```
class Favorite extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'project_id'
    ];

    public function favorite() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function project() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Project', 'project_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Now I do know that I am only asking to give me the user_id or project_id on my Blade page, I did this because something like $act->creator->name or $act->project->title would give me an error like:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$creator

or

> Undefined property: stdClass::$project

I do get that this might have to do something with the way I build my query and that mixing tables this way might have made things more difficult than they should be, but I can't seem to find a way to build this query in Eloquent or to find a way to reach the data that belong to these user_id's and project_id's without having to use the public functions I've created in my models.

Comment: In order to use the model relations, you need to create a model instance. Calling SQL queries directly would not create models. So to help further, how are the tables built and what do you want to retrieve from the SQL?

Comment: Basically the comment, like and favorite table have the same structure, they have an ID, user_id and project_id, the last two have a relationship with the corresponding user or project in my database. The project table only has a relationship with the users table. Most of all I'd like to get things like the name of a project or user, that's why I tried to use the model relations. I can get all the data when I use a query for each table individually, but I'd like to sort everything based on the time that's included, that's why I combined the tables, but now I only get the ID's, no other data.

Comment: OK, with the current setup, you cannot benefit from the Laravel models, as you need to loop through different models. My recommendation is to build a new table called Activity, with 3 columns: id, type, user_id. And use Polymorphic relationship.

Comment: I'd second what @MinaYoussef says. Create a new table Activity with the references you need like: id, type (like, comment, favourite, project, ...), user_id, created_at. Insert a new record in the Activity table whenever such an action (like commenting on a project) occurs. That way, you can simply query the activity table in reverse chronological order and load meta data when needed. If you want to use Polymorphic relationships, check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lePjXdMC6aM

Comment: Thanks @Jorre, also you can benefit from Laravel queuing system, create an event once a Like, Comment,... is created, and the Listener is a queued job that creates the other Activity entry in the DB. This way you have 1 query less during the online request.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @MinaYoussef and Jorre, by making an Activity table is was able to display everything just the way I wanted.

Comment: @MinaYoussef can you add your answer below, so that it can be marked as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

With the current setup, you cannot benefit from the Laravel models, as you need to loop through different models. My recommendation is to build a new table called Activity, with 3 columns: id, type, user_id. And use Polymorphic relationship.

Also, you can benefit from Events/Listeners, in order to create the records in the Activity table. You can benefit from the Queued Listeners, so the  Activity records are not created online, if this won't impact your customer experience.